# PHP Format/Validate Date

Tags: php, date, format

Say I am assuming a date format of `DDMMYYY` is being sent to me. However, somebody may send `01022014`, another may send `1022014`, another may send `122014` and yet another the year can be given just as `14`. This last case is not very significant. I am more worried about the day and the month.

How can I validate the date, and accept all of these format, and then reformat it to what I want in PHP?

Comment: do you want to insert data in database?

Comment: use regular expressions to allow your given date formates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is you can't. You have to enforce the formatting rule in the frontend somehow. For example, show the months as a select drop down to remove ambiguity and reduce the possibility of human errors.

Comment: The dates from the url as in page/dd/mm/yyyy. So the problem is it is natural to type in page/1/1/2014 as oppose to page/01/01/2014 and also easier to create links to the actual day, without a leading zero.